# android: The google maps 8.4.0 version is crashing for some devices

Tags: android, google-maps

We're facing an issue with the maps is some phones. Here's the open [issue in the google repo](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=203336). None of the comments on the issue is helpful.

We are using  8.4.0 version and we have no clue how to fix or catch this crash.
This is hapening only in some devices example : LGE LG-P970 Android 4.0.4 API 15.
We're using the SupportMapFragment.

The stack trace is not giving any details:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NullPointerException
    at maps.dz.o.a(Unknown Source)
    at maps.dg.e.a(Unknown Source)
    at maps.dg.u.a(Unknown Source)
    at maps.ei.ag.a(Unknown Source)
    at maps.ei.bu.a(Unknown Source)
    at maps.ei.n$1.a(Unknown Source)
    at maps.ei.n.a(Unknown Source)                 
    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.i$a.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms.alldynamite:107) 
   at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:297) 
   at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.IMapFragmentDelegate$zza$zza.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$zza.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza$4.zzb(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza.zza(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
   at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1974)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1252)
   at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1617)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:517)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4516)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Did anybody face this issue? any fix (or work around) is welcome.

Thanks!

Comment: `NullPointerException` - are you able to narrow to the place in your code  that trigger the crash? Bug may not be in your code - maybe bug is theirs and you just managed to trigger it, but knowing how to repro the issue would either help or allow you to fill bug report agains Maps

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't, neither how to reproduce, it doesn't happen in all phones, just in some like an LGE LG Android 4.0.4 API 15. I added some infos to the question. thanks.

Comment: having same issue, looks like Android bug https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Introduced%20Fixed%20Summary%20Stars%20ApiType%20Internal&groupby=&sort=&id=9163

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I observe this crash in activity which dynamically changes fragments when Android device connected to computer in USB debug mode. **Without USB connection application works fine.**

Stack trace is not very helpful:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{xxx}: java.lang.NullPointerException
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2338)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2388)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:148)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1319)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5473)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:806)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:622)
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
   at maps.dz.o.a(Unknown Source)
   at maps.dg.e.a(Unknown Source)
   at maps.dg.p.a(Unknown Source)
   at maps.ei.ag.a(Unknown Source)
   at maps.ei.bu.a(Unknown Source)
   at maps.ei.n$1.a(Unknown Source)
   at maps.ei.n.a(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.i$a.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms.alldynamite:107)
   at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:347)
   at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.IMapFragmentDelegate$zza$zza.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$zza.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza$4.zzb(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza.zza(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
   at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1962)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1248)
   at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1613)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.execPendingActions(FragmentController.java:330)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:547)
   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1171)
   at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5244)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2311)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2388) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:148) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1319) 
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5473) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:806) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:622) 
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Device: Huawei G535-L11, Android 4.3

Workaround: disconnect device from USB before launching the app

Comment: having same issue, looks like Android bug https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Introduced%20Fixed%20Summary%20Stars%20ApiType%20Internal&groupby=&sort=&id=9163